# Converting timestamp to Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
todayminus1 = (today - BDay(1))
print("type(todayminus1) =", type(todayminus1))
todayminus1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(todayminus1).strftime('%d-%m-%y')

print("todayminus1 =", todayminus1)

error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

I cant work this out. Any ideas?

Seems to be getting an error when trying to convert to datetime

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

> classmethod datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=None) Return the
> local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is
> returned by time.time(). If optional argument tz is None or not
> specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and
> time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

You need to convert your timestamp to the UNIX time using `todayminus1.timestamp()`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
todayminus1 = (today - BDay(1))
print("type(todayminus1) =", type(todayminus1))
todayminus1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(todayminus1.timestamp()).strftime('%d-%m-%y')

print("todayminus1 =", todayminus1)
```

Output:

```
type(todayminus1) = <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
todayminus1 = 23-06-21
```

As an addition, you shouldnt mix between pandas and datetime. So, you could also add `.to_pydatetime()` on the line:

```
todayminus1 = (today - BDay(1)).to_pydatetime()
```

to keep everything as `datetime`.